# Parsing tweets to extract hashtags in R

Tags: r, parsing, hashtag

I was wondering if anyone has a quick solution to extracting hashtags from the tweets in `R`.
For example, given the following string, how can I parse it to extract the word with the hashtag?

```
string <- 'Crowdsourcing is awesome. #stackoverflow'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I expect you probably *can* parse hashtags with regex.

```
library(stringr)
string <- "#hashtag Crowd#sourcing is awesome. #stackoverflow #question"
# I don't use Twitter, so maybe this regex is not right 
# for the set of allowable hashtag characters.
hashtag.regex <- perl("(?<=^|\\s)#\\S+")
hashtags <- str_extract_all(string, hashtag.regex)
```

Which yields:

```
> print(hashtags)
[[1]]
[1] "#hashtag"       "#stackoverflow" "#question"
```

Note that this also works unmodified if `string` is actually a vector of many tweets. It returns a list of character vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string <- c('Crowdsourcing is awesome. #stackoverflow #answer', 
    "another #tag in this tweet")
step1 <- strsplit(string, "#")
step2 <- lapply(step1, tail, -1)
result <- lapply(step2, function(x){
  sapply(strsplit(x, " "), head, 1)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if tweets are of different length/word counts. Is there any more general way to only obtain hashtags? I have more than 20,000 tweets.